# How to return all the indexes of a list inputted by the user with this function?

Tags: python, list, function, loops

With this code I expect to get an output of what the user is introducing in the console in numbers_x to get iterated by the function below, but the output only returns me the last element of the expected list, how can I get all the indexes of the list?

```
def listas(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(0,n):
         elementos = int(float(input(f"Enter your number {i+1}:    ")))
    list(lst)
    lst.append(elementos)
    print(type(lst))
    return lst


numbers_x = listas(n=(int(input("Enter the total numbers of your list: "))))

print(numbers_x)
```

##Output##

```
Enter the total numbers of your list: 4
Enter your number 1:    1
Enter your number 2:    2
Enter your number 3:    3
Enter your number 4:    4
<class 'list'>
[4] #I expect that the output here, was [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You need to append to `lst` inside the loop. Otherwise you're just appending the last value of `elementos`.

Comment: `list(lst)` doesn't do anything useful. It's already a list so you don't need to convert it. And you're not assigning the result to anything.

Answer (score 0):

you were appending items to the list at the wrong point in the code. Remember, the for loop runs n number of times, and EACH time the user puts a number input in you have to add that to the list before the next item in the for loop runs:

```
def list_input_retrieval(n):
    my_list = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        print('got to for loop: i is {index}'.format(index=i))
        elements = int(float(input(f"Enter your number {i+1}:    ")))
        my_list.append(elements)
    return my_list



input_list = list_input_retrieval(5)

print(input_list)
```

Notice doing both `int` and `float` at the same time is redundant, since your function doesn't round numbers as expected. You could remove `float` and I think it would work the same:

```
$ python3 script.py 
Enter your number 1:    5.6
Enter your number 2:    7.6
Enter your number 3:    5.2
Enter your number 4:    6.8
Enter your number 5:    8.9
[5, 7, 5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def listas(n):
    return [int(input(f"Enter your number {i+1}: ")) for i in range(n)]


numbers_x = listas(int(input("Enter the total numbers of your list: ")))

print(numbers_x)
```

It will ask the user for `n` of list element and pass it the value to function `listas`. The user will input the value of lista based on `n` numbers using list comprehension and the `numbers_x` will return the value of `listas`

Or you can use one liner without function:

```
numbers_x = [int(input(f"Enter your number {i+1}: ")) for i in range(int(input("Enter the total numbers of your list: ")))]

print(numbers_x)
```

Output:

```
Enter the total numbers of your list: 4
Enter your number 1: 1
Enter your number 2: 2
Enter your number 3: 3
Enter your number 4: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]

Process finished with exit code 0
```